# Remove border from wxBitmapButton

Tags: c++, user-interface, wxwidgets

when I run my application under Ubuntu (Gnome/Unity) all wxBitmapButtons come with a white border (with a size of about 2..4 pixels). This border also shifts the position and extends the size of the total button by the borders size.

When I specify flag wxNO_BORDER (or wxBORDER_NONE) the border is no longer shown by default bur re-appears on mouse-over.

So my question: how can I remove this border completely? Normal wxButtons do not show this behaviour, only wxBitmapButton is affected...

Answer (score 0):

`wxBORDER_NONE` is supposed to work, so if it doesn't, it looks like a bug in wxGTK. It's pretty strange that it does work for `wxButton`s as `wxBitmapButton` is basically the same class. However if it's really the case, you should consider just using `wxButton` with a bitmap instead.